# Bidirectional type-safe mapping functions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a need to map between two vocabularies such as:

```
GB <--> United_Kingdom
FR <--> France
```

I want to be able to define the mapping in one place and have functions to map between these values in either direction and in a type safe way.

This is the desired functionality in JavaScript, but I can't work out how to make it type safe:

```
function createMappers(map) {
  const invertedMap = Object.entries(map).reduce(
    (inverted, [key, value]) => ({ ...inverted, [value]: key }),
    {},
  );
  const leftToRight = (from) => map[from];
  const rightToLeft = (to) => invertedMap[to];

  return [leftToRight, rightToLeft];
}


// I want to specify this mapping only once
const map = { a: "A", b: "B" };


const [toRight, toLeft] = createMappers(map);

const one = toRight("a");
//    ^^^ should be typed 'A' | 'B' (or, even better, just 'A')
const two = toLeft("B");
//    ^^^ should be typed 'a' | 'b' (or, even better, just 'b')
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nr8y2W) meet your needs? I'm assuming by "type safe" you mean the *callers* of `createMappers()` get strong types.  It's hard for the *implementer* to get type safety verified by the compiler and I mostly skipped it by doing a lot of assertions.  Let me know if you want to see this as an answer or if I'm missing something.

Comment: That's perfect!  Please post as answer. I think the key missing ingredient was `as const` on the source object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you want the compiler to know about the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"A"` and `"B"` of the property values in your `map` object, then you'll need to change how it's typed.  The default heuristics TS uses to give types to objects with string literal properties is to widen the types of the properties to `string` , since modifying properties is a very common use case.  If you want narrower types you can tell the compiler you never plan to modify `map` at all by using a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on its initializer:

```
const map = { a: "A", b: "B" } as const;
// const map: { readonly a: "A"; readonly b: "B"; }
```

---

Now we can give `createMappers()` strong typings.  Here's one way to do it:

```
function createMappers<M extends Record<keyof M, PropertyKey>>(map: M) {
    const invertedMap = (Object.entries(map) as Array<[PropertyKey, PropertyKey]>).reduce(
        (inverted, [key, value]) => ({ ...inverted, [value]: key }),
        {},
    ) as Invert<M>;
    const leftToRight = <K extends keyof M>(from: K) => map[from];
    const rightToLeft = <K extends keyof Invert<M>>(to: K) => invertedMap[to];

    return [leftToRight, rightToLeft] as const;
}
```

The function is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `M`, the type of the `map` parameter.  It is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Record<keyof M, PropertyKey>`, meaning that it must have key-like property *values* at every key.  This will allow us to invert the mapping in the type system.

The creation of `invertedMap` in the implementation is too complicated for the compiler to understand the typing, so I just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that it will be of the type `Invert<M>`, a utility type I'll describe later which swaps keys and values.

Finally, the `leftToRight` and `rightToLeft` functions are generic in `K`, the type of their inputs, and we return `[leftToRight, rightToLeft]`, also `const` asserted, so that the compiler understands that this meant to be a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of exactly two strongly-typed elements and not an unordered and arbitrary-length array type.

The resulting call signature is

```
/* function createMappers<M extends Record<keyof M, PropertyKey>>(
      map: M
    ): readonly [
        <K extends keyof M>(from: K) => M[K], 
        <K extends keyof Invert<M>>(to: K) => Invert<M>[K]
    ]; */
```

Which looks good as long as we know what `Invert<M>` is.  Here it is:

```
type Invert<M extends Record<keyof M, PropertyKey>> = 
  { [K in keyof M as M[K]]: K }
```

This is a [mapped type with key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as); all it does is, for each property of `M`, produce an output property with the key and value swapped.

---

Okay, let's test it out:

```
const [toRight, toLeft] = createMappers(map);

/* const toRight: <K extends "a" | "b">(from: K) => {
    readonly a: "A";
    readonly b: "B";
}[K] 

const toLeft: <K extends "A" | "B">(to: K) => Invert<{
    readonly a: "A";
    readonly b: "B";
}>[K] */
```

Looks good so far, how does it work when we call them?

```
const one = toRight("a");
// const one: "A"
const two = toLeft("B");
// const two: "b"
```

Great, the compiler knows exactly what comes out for each call, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?experimentalDecorators=false&jsx=0&module=7&suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors=false&pretty=true&ts=4.9.5&ssl=19&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=10#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgNwgJ2AHgLJQgD2BOAEwGcoAlCAYwHtlC0BrCEagMygwBooAFZayKhABpZgD4xUALxQA3lADawqAEs4UJi3ZYAhqQxKAuoYBcUZQF8AUFdYBXOJWArq6ysgg78GHWEHFMbDwCEnIqWnpNNg5uPgEUUFEQCQAKAFtfMwwASjkrKAKoGjhiYFVEBIhCHzBpKBSAeQAjACsqYAA6AmBkFQhidN9cvSgAQWRkHRA0BTjBROZY-nmRZkMxbI6PQjtKCBT8wqOUtSRUKu4FTW4EHQAbOwhDXKlJFPkOz9PKwkvbh6eZk0UAs2U4hyOBVkFnBR2GpHgZ3QGDEAG4IUVXKUoHcIKxgAAVahkFQAcwAFmUZGhlLh8ERSFFtGIUqx+GkzMIXpIMmAFGzqGlDOijsVsb0KYTqAAZPFUqA0oL00JM2AVVCYVLAaic7nlJFVGoKbXCmxHDzAOzIdQKXH4okkyXcCWUomy-GGKAjMXAdHWAD0ACooPZHM5XEUPF4IDV-IE6SFSBQaHRGMxolxeMsEqtkiyMQVeVkMdkzFHCK47iBFAXCoqEwyNOnmaz2brpJIDMJDNxawV68FG6rEQlNSzte3XmqkZqjBjhVBA-6bP7-bAoAB3HRwMraqDESCUFSsavAckqUi8sBqUlQSvV1x7Kw+qC8uryHRmABEoy-3Ca34AEJfiCXqkD66KrpiJRlEWchQOW95et+v6oghngVnAVZQABUBfsBaHWM+WJlMaxJkpS3Dau6wCejI7ieN4vj+IMYDZOiVhBtB2Lao6lJmAOyqkF+OggQAPnhTRfiyAocuYeqyBiiFYdWn54ahSkYUhuH4V+fpGFANgvtRcoCbSg6hD+4l4cB446vJHbTqOinmlpKnIepemaTomHYTpBFWBYYhzlYS5GSRd5wNAMi8RRwApCJX7sZxa4vq4EAoV+xEwVAwAbtQdQmfiCXAclUHGfl35SVYQA)